# Implicit conversion during overload resolution

Tags: c++, overload-resolution

Is there a way for the c++ compiler to perform implicit conversion during operator overload resolution?

For example, I'd like the last line in the following example to compile and behave the same way as the previous line.

```
struct A
{
private:
    int _val;
public:
    A ( int val ) : _val( val ) {}
    A operator+( A a ) { return _val + a._val; }
};

struct B
{
private:
    int _val;
public:
    B ( int val ) : _val( val ) {}
    operator A () { return _val; }
};

int main()
{
    B b1 = { 0 }, b2 = { 1 };

    auto a = static_cast<A>( b1 ) + b2; // Works
    //auto a = b1 + b2;                 // Doesn't work
}
```

Comment: `b1` and `b2` are `B`s, so the compiler is only going to look for an operator where one or both operands are `B`s.

Comment: Implicit conversions aren't a problem, as long as there's only one that would work.

Comment: C++ doesn't work this way, the rules are what they are. It shouldn't be to difficult to define an additional overload that effects this.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

When you have two `B` objects, the compiler is going to look for an `operator+` inside `B` or in the global namespace, so it can't find them in `A`.

Place the operator where it can be found instead (rewriting it as a non-member function):

```cpp
struct A
{
private:
    int _val;
public:
    A ( int val ) : _val( val ) {}
    friend A operator+(A l, A r) { return l._val + r._val; };
};

A operator+(A l, A r);
```

Now `b1 + b2;` will find `A operator+(A l, A r);` and call it after implicitly converting both arguments.